# Cropping an image with imagepickercontroller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently making a program in swift that involves a screen of choosing an image from either camera or photo library using action sheet. This is fully functional however I would like to be able to choose a square section from the selected image, similar to apple default apps. How can I implement this? Here is my functional code:

```
func chooseImage(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "Choose a source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            print("Camera not available")
        }


    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Default", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        self.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Avatar.png")


    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    avatarImageView.image = image

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
// Saves the User singleton object onto the device
static func saveData() {
    let savedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: User.sharedUser)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(savedData, forKey: "user")
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use default controls to achieve image cropping.

```
self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = true
```

Delegate Method

```
//MARK: image picker delegate method
    //MARK:
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        var image : UIImage!

        if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        {
            image = img

        }
        else if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        {
            image = img
        }


        picker.dismiss(animated: true,completion: nil)
 }
```

Comment: On Android crop is pain in the a... on iOS single line of code!

Comment: Solution does not fully work for me. Image is not cropped correctly. What could this be? Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810844/issue-with-imagepickercontroller-cropping)

Comment: here the crop aspect ratio is only square, I need free crop. Anyone face such issue?

Comment: @dakshbhatt21, This is default functionality you can not modify it. Yes you can use many third party library for crop image.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 4.0+

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    var image : UIImage!

    if let img = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        image = img

    }
    else if let img = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        image = img
    }


    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Don't forget to set allowsEditing to true.

Another option is to use [TOCropViewController](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController). Its does more with much less code. What I found good about it that it allows you to change the cropping rectangle.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CropViewControllerDelegate {

    ... //your viewcontroller code

    func presentCropViewController {
        let image: UIImage = ... //Load an image

        let cropViewController = CropViewController(image: image)
        cropViewController.delegate = self
        present(cropViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: CropViewController, 
         didCropToImage image: UIImage, withRect cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {
        // 'image' is the newly cropped version of the original image
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for tip about TOCropViewController

Answer (score 5):

```
Swift 5.0
```

The shortest way of declaring:

```
//MARK: image picker delegate method
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

     var image : UIImage!
     if let img = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
         image = img
     } else if let img = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
         image = img
     }
     picker.dismiss(animated: true,completion: nil)
 }
```

Button sender:

```
@objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton!) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

> - Don't forget to grant Photo Library access in .plist

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)cropViewController:(TOCropViewController *)cropViewController didCropToImage:(UIImage *)image withRect:(CGRect)cropRect angle:(NSInteger)angle
```

{

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) forKey:@"image"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"cameraOn"];

[cropViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];

}];
//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

}

For (iOS13): Do all ViewController "cropController.modalPresentationStyle =.fullScreen"  using  storyboard or code.

This is work good and easily navigate to another controller. I also attached image so you can easily understand how to change presentation style.

[image: storyboard images]

Answer (score 0):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            profilePicImageView.image = image
            profilePicImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicImageView.frame.height/2
        } else if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            profilePicImageView.image = image
            profilePicImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicImageView.frame.height/2
        }
    }
```

also give a nice rounded shape to your image view upon image selection.