# Issue with ImagePickerController cropping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'd like user to be able to crop images they've selected from photo library via `ImagePickerController`.

Ive allowed editing.

```
self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = true
```

And retrieve edited version of image.

```
let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
```

The top of the image is not fully cropped. This is Apples code. Do I need to implement something custom?

**Crop** (should only show image, all white is cropped out):

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by **The top of the image is not fully cropped**  It looks like you should change your imageView's aspect ratio or content mode

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Please take another look. I added another photo to show how the white space at top should be cropped out. I will take a look at content mode & aspect ratio as well. thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a default behavior when you click picture from the camera this issue won't arise but when you pick a picture from the photo gallery it will be there.

You can always use the alternative in your case I would suggest [YPImagePicker](https://github.com/Yummypets/YPImagePicker)

OR you can crop the image manually refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904940/issue-with-uiimagepickercontrollereditedimage)

I hope it helps.